# Is there an API for retrieving up-to-date intraday 1 minute bar data by Date AND Time ranges?

Tags: market-data, historical-data, tick-data

I'm looking for an API that has an endpoint for fetching 1min bar data by Time in at least a minute of precision as opposed to just by date.

Comment: Do you want historial or real-time? And what asset class?

Answer (score 1):

Barchart.com has such an API. It is not free (but I am not aware of any intraday data for free, except when sandboxed [on Quantopian, e.g.]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Polygon.io provides the endpoint I'm looking for for $199/month, they just hadn't indicated in their docs that in addition to date ranges, one can also use timestamp ranges to find ticks intraday within specific intraday ranges.